# Upload audio file to Parse REST API via Flask

Tags: python, flask, parse-platform

I am trying to upload an audio recording to Parse via their REST API. I am uploading the blob to my Flask app and then converting that file to a base64 string to be sent to Parse.

The response from Parse is that the upload was successful, but the audio file doesn't play when browsing to the file on Parse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

file.wav is the audio recording in an uint8array

```
// js
ParleData.Upload = function(file) {
   var dataView = new DataView(file.wav.buffer);
   var blob = new Blob([dataView], { type: 'audio/x-wav' });

   var form = new FormData();
   form.append('file', blob, 'audio.wav');

   return $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/upload',
      contentType: false,
      processData:false,
      cache:false,
      data: form
   });
}

# views.py
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
   wav = request.files['file']
   return jsonify(DAS.upload(wav))

# das.py
def upload(self, wav):
    b64 = base64.b64encode(wav.read())

    connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.parse.com', 443)
    connection.connect();
    connection.request('POST', 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/audio', b64, {
    'X-Parse-Application-Id':self.keys.X_PARSE_APP_ID,
    'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':self.keys.X_PARSE_RESTAPI_ID,
    'Content-Type': "audio/x-wav"
    })
    return json.loads(connection.getresponse().read())
```

Comment: Did you try to play audio after it is uploaded? I mean, you turn it into a base64 stream. Get this stream and turn back into an file and try reproduce it to check if reverse process is ok.

Comment: Does the upload fail if you don't base64 encode?  Seems like an unnecessary step.

Comment: @wberry I can't believe I never tried not encoding, passing wav.read() instead of b64 fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base64 encode step is unnecessary.  The file can be posted without any transformation and should be playable.  If you can use a streaming upload, this may improve the performance of the client also.